# nested tabular loses top-alignment in cells and inserts additional linebreak

Tags: tables

When I use nested tables in order to insert line-breaks in my tabular object, I get unexpected alignment in the other cells in that row

e.g. in row A, I expect col 1 and col 4 to maintain their top alignment as per row B, and I certainly don't expect col 4 to wrap for a third line, when this is not required by any of the cells in this row.  Not sure I've explained it very well but the below example should make it clear...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{my caption}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}llp{7cm}}
\hline
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 & col 4 \\ \hline
A & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}v1\\ v2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]    {@{}l@{}}v3\\ v4\end{tabular} & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\ \hline
B & v5 & v6 & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile starting with `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`. This will be much more useful than fragments.

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}[t]`? Or whatever. Or use a `p{}` column?

Comment: @cfr I've changed the nested tables to [t] as you suggest and it worked - do you want to put it as an answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: also...why would the internal alignment of the nested table affect the alignment of the parent table? that isn't clear to me, which is why I didn't test that as a possible solution...tho I feel a bit silly that it was such a simple fix :)

Comment: It is not internal alignment - it is the alignment of the tabular relative to the current baseline i.e. external alignment of the tabular, if you like.

Comment: ah - that makes way more sense - thankyou!

Comment: I wouldn't feel silly. Nobody finds LaTeX's alignment specifications intuitive. However, I didn't know why you'd used `c`. Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked for the tabular to be centred relative to the current baseline with `[c]`. Hence, the tabular is centred on that baseline. To see this note that the line break is at the vertical centre of the `A` in the first column. The `p{}` column type is aligned at the top line and so the first line in this column is aligned to the current baseline also. That is, the output you see is exactly what is expected given the options you've chosen.

Moreover, as it stands your code also produces bad boxes when completed in the obvious way to create a proper minimal example, so it is necessary to trim the `p{}` columns a bit to fit the tabular to the width of the text block.

To fix the alignment, you probably want `t` rather than `c`. I'm not sure about this because I don't understand why you would think you wanted `c` or what you expected the output to be. I'm assuming you want something like this:

[image: possibly desired output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{my caption}
  \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}llp{6cm}}
    \hline
    col 1 & col 2 & col 3 & col 4 \\
    \hline
    A & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}v1\\v2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}v3\\v4\end{tabular} & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\
    \hline
    B & v5 & v6 & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, I would recommend something more like this:

[image: suggested output]

provided, of course, the first column will really contain more content. Otherwise, you should obviously rebalance the column widths. (In that case, I'd probably use an `X` column for the last one with **tabularx** and `lll` for the first 3.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{my caption}
  \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}llp{6cm}}
    \toprule
    col 1 & col 2 & col 3 & col 4 \\
    \midrule
    A & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}v1\\v2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}v3\\v4\end{tabular} & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
    B & v5 & v6 & here is a long line that tends to go for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that we have assigned it \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - tbh the [c] was an artefact of a table generator, but because I was looking at the alignment of the parent table I didn't think to modify the alignment of the nested one...my interpretation of that [c] was that it was asking for the nested tables to centre vertically which was irrelevant to my issue because each of the nested cells were just 1char long - shouldn't have assumed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative where instead of nested `tabular`s is used `\makecell[lt]{...}` macro from `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\caption{my caption}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}llp{7cm}}
\hline
col 1   &   col 2   & col 3 & col 4                     \\ \hline
A       &   \makecell[lt]{v1\\ v2} 
                    &   \makecell[lt]{v3\\ v4} 
                            &   here is a long line that tends to go for 
                                somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that 
                                we have assigned it     \\ \hline
B       &   v5      &   v6  &   here is a long line that tends to go 
                                for somewhat longer than the assigned 7cm that 
                                we have assigned it     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Code is shorter and more easy to read (at least to my opinion). Meaning of options `lt` in `\makecell` macro is: `l` for left (horisontal) align and `t` for top (vertical) align. Result is:

[image]